# "OSError: [Errno 5] EIO" when running my code

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, thonny

Error:

```
>>> %Run -c $EDITOR_CONTENT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/lib/ssd1306.py", line 110, in __init__
  File "/lib/ssd1306.py", line 36, in __init__
  File "/lib/ssd1306.py", line 71, in init_display
  File "/lib/ssd1306.py", line 115, in write_cmd
OSError: [Errno 5] EIO
```

My script:

```
from machine import Pin, I2C
from ssd1306 import SSD1306_I2C

i2c = I2C(0, sda=Pin(16), scl=Pin(17), freq=40000)
oled = SSD1306_I2C(128, 64, i2c)

oled.fill(0)
oled.text("Hello", 0, 0)
oled.show()
import machine
import ssd1306
import time

# Define the pins for I2C communication
i2c = machine.I2C(0, sda=machine.Pin(16), scl=machine.Pin(17), freq=400000)

# Define the display object
oled = ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(128, 64, i2c)

# Clear the display
oled.fill(0)
oled.show()

# Display something
oled.text("Hello, Pico!", 0, 0)
oled.show()
```

What causes the issue?

Comment: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=339160 exactly the same issue

Comment: Maybe try scanning the I2C bus to make sure your display is wired correctly and detected.
```
print('Scanning i2c bus...');
devices = i2c.scan();

if (len(devices) == 0):
    print("No i2c device !");
else:
    print('Devices found:', len(devices));
    for address in devices:  
        print("Address: ", hex(address));
```
Sorry, Markdown formatting doesn't work in the comments. I put semicolons at line ends to help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a raspberry pi pico with a DS3231 real time clock module and I solved it switching the microPython version to [RPI_PICO-20231005-v1.21.0.uf2](https://micropython.org/download/rp2-pico/rp2-pico-latest.uf2)

Source:

- https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/micropython.html

  "Download the correct MicroPython UF2 file for your board:"